# Content script's sendResponse never reaches service worker's sendMessage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

tl; dr: I'm implementing a runtime listener in a content script, where I do a `sendMessage` to it from background.js. The problem is that, when doing this way, the callback of the function in background.js is never executed.

---

I have this [function](https://github.com/FantasticoFox/VerifyPage/blob/9e085915398da55553534e64e965398fe12e3d07/src/verifier.ts#L104), which is executed by my service worker (background.js) which does a `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to the content script of an active tab. This is the [content script](https://github.com/FantasticoFox/VerifyPage/blob/9e085915398da55553534e64e965398fe12e3d07/src/content_script.tsx).

The problem is that the callback for `sendMessage` is never executed, even though if I do a `console.log` inside the content script, it shows up. There is no `runtime.LastError` either.
I have tried to manually do `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(37, {color: "FOO"}, resp=>console.log)` in the console of my extension. But the console always terminates whenever I do this.
My content script function is synchronous, and so there is no need to do `return true;`. Even if I add `return true;`, the problem is still there.

Comment: Content scripts run when the tab [re]loads so when you reload/update the extension they won't run. You can manually inject the content script in chrome.runtime.onInstalled event but a much better approach would be to remove `content_scripts` altogether and just use chrome.scripting.executeScript with `func` to get the data.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had tried `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to no avail, but will try it again. I will report back my finding.

Comment: @wOxxOm using `executeScript` works! I'm happy to accept your comment if you turn it into an answer. My previous `executeScript` implementation was wrong in that I thought the injection result is the string I generated from `executeScript`, where in fact it is an array of injection results. I will clarify my question and make it more generic. My situation is that I'm putting a listener in the content script, and do `sendMessage` from background.js, which is not common (if it were common, I'd have found SO questions about it;)).